# LuaInterface event handling

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I have looked around for a good tutorial on how to Handle events using LuaInterface, but am still stuck trying to find one that actually explains what must be done in detail.

Could someone write up a simple tutorial, or point me in the direction of one?

Thanks
Twitchy

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a tutorial on LuaInterface](http://penlight.luaforge.net/packages/LuaInterface/). From the form examples there:

```
button.Click:Add(function()
    MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!","Title",MessageBoxButtons.OK)
end)
```